# How can I show the data from a XML file follow list format?

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a problem with jQuery and XML. 
I am using jQuery to load data from a XML file. It works fine
but I want to show data follow list format with its title , when I click the title the info of its will show.
How can I do it?

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "xml/tuyendung.xml",
    dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

        var newXML = parseXml(xml);


        $(newXML).find('TDDetail').each(function(){

            var emailid = $(this).attr('email');
            var tdcode = $(this).attr('tdcode');
            var title = $(this).find('jobtitle').text();
            var position = $(this).find('positiontitle').text();
            var jobdescribe= $(this).find('jobdescribe').text();
            var jobexperience= $(this).find('jobexperience').text();
            var jobskills= $(this).find('jobskills').text();
            var jobtime= $(this).find('jobtime').text();
            var joblocation= $(this).find('joblocation').text();
            var jobcategory= $(this).find('jobcategory').text();
            var joblevel= $(this).find('joblevel').text();
            var jobsalary= $(this).find('jobsalary').text();
            var ecount=0;
            matd=new Array();


                if($(this).attr('email')==GetCookie('Email') && tdcode==tdcode  )
                {       


                    $('<div class="items" id="link_'+tdcode+'"></div>').html('<a href="javascript:hienthi()">'+title+'</a>').appendTo('#textb');

                }                               

            });

        }
    });
});
```

and my XML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<TD>
    <TDDetail email="cspniit@gmail.com" tdcode="TD001" jobtitle="quan ly">
        <jobtitle>Quan ly</jobtitle>
        <positiontitle>Manager</positiontitle>
        <jobdescribe>Quan ly nhan su cong ty ABC</jobdescribe>
        <jobexperience>2</jobexperience>
        <jobskills>Anh van giao tiep tot. Chung chi tin hoc B</jobskills>
        <jobtime>Fulltime</jobtime>
        <joblocation>CanTho</joblocation>
        <jobcategory>IT-Software</jobcategory>
        <joblevel>Manager</joblevel>
        <jobsalary>thoa thuan</jobsalary>
    </TDDetail>
    <TDDetail email="cspniit@gmail.com" tdcode="TD002" jobtitle="quan ly ma">
        <jobtitle>Quan ly ma</jobtitle>
        <positiontitle>Manager</positiontitle>
        <jobdescribe>Quan ly nhan su cong ty ABC</jobdescribe>
        <jobexperience>2</jobexperience>
        <jobskills>Anh van giao tiep tot. Chung chi tin hoc B</jobskills>
        <jobtime>Fulltime</jobtime>
        <joblocation>CanTho</joblocation>
        <jobcategory>IT-Software</jobcategory>
        <joblevel>Manager</joblevel>
        <jobsalary>canh tranh</jobsalary>
    </TDDetail>
    <TDDetail email="aa@gmail.com" tdcode="TD003" jobtitle="giam doc">
        <jobtitle>Giam Doc Van Phong</jobtitle>
        <positiontitle>Manager</positiontitle>
        <jobdescribe>Quan ly nhan su cong ty ABC</jobdescribe>
        <jobexperience>2</jobexperience>
        <jobskills>Anh van giao tiep tot. Chung chi tin hoc B</jobskills>
        <jobtime>Fulltime</jobtime>
        <joblocation>CanTho</joblocation>
        <jobcategory>IT-Software</jobcategory>
        <joblevel>Manager</joblevel>
        <jobsalary>compete</jobsalary>
    </TDDetail>
    <TDDetail email="cspniit@gmail.com" tdcode="TD003"><jobtitle>Giao hang</jobtitle><positiontitle>employee</positiontitle><jobdescribe>Tuyen nhan vien gio hang trong noi thanh Can Tho</jobdescribe><jobexperience>0</jobexperience><jobskills>Lanh le , gioi viec</jobskills><jobtime>Parttime</jobtime><joblocation>CanTho</joblocation><jobcategory>Sale</jobcategory><joblevel>graduate</joblevel><jobsalary>thoa thuan</jobsalary></TDDetail></TD>
```

Comment: You don't actually use the xml anywhere....

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to:

<s>var newXML = parseXml(xml);</s>

and just use directly xml as :

```
        $(xml).find(.......
```

**edit**

```
 /space/ <?xml version="1.0"?>
```

please check if there is a space before `<?xml ...` that sometimes could give error to IE... the markup... you can do validation check [here](http://validator.w3.org/).